# java script split error

Tags: javascript, split

I am using the onCellClick function of Sigma Grid to allow the user to select from a grid and have a form updated with the selected information.

When I try to split the record that is returned from onCellClick (which returns the record associated with the grid row) I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" pointing to the split line.

```
onCellClick : function(value, record, cell, row, colNO, rowNO, columnObj, grid){
            var recordCurrent = record;
            var recordSplit = recordCurrent.split(",");
            alert("Participant is " + recordSplit[1]);
            }
```

If I do an alert showing the unsplit record from the onCellClick event it shows the data I expect.

I am missing something obvious.  Any direction you can provide will be appreciated.

Comment: Check recordCurrent type if it's not string (so, it's not) you cannot split.

Comment: Even, as Enes mentioned, if you can split it there's still a chance there won't be a value in the 2nd position

Answer (score 1):

The error you received `"Object doesn't support this property or method"` would suggest that you are attempting to call `.split` on something that doesn't have it (not a string).

You should check that your parameters are the types you expect before you work with them:

```
if (typeof record !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('You must pass a string as the record to onCellClick!');
} else {
    var recordCurrent = record;
    var recordSplit = recordCurrent.split(",");
    alert("Participant is " + recordSplit[1]);
}
```

Upon further investigation, [Sigma grid documentation](http://www.sigmawidgets.com/products/sigma_grid2/docs/sigma_grid.html#oncellclick) states that the type of the `record` parameter is `Object` or `Array`, not `String`.

Comment: Thank you.  It was indeed an object.  Converting it to a string using var str = "" + obj; solved the problem.  Thank you again.

Comment: @hwilliams you're welcome. if the answer helped you and you think it will help other people with a similar problem, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You should perform two checks:

1) That there is actually a record

2) That the split record has more than one object in it

```
onCellClick : function(value, record, cell, row, colNO, rowNO, columnObj, grid){
    if (record.length) {
        var recordSplit = record.split(",");
        if (recordSplit.length > 1) {
            alert("Participant is " + recordSplit[1]);
        }
    }
}
```